# INSERT INTO using data from other table causing ERROR 1064

Tags: mysql, select, myisam, insert-into

My command for INSERT INTO was:

```
INSERT INTO environment_fid (FID_environment) VALUES SELECT ID FROM environment WHERE name='planes';
```

But I got:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT ID FROM environment WHERE name='planes'' at line 1

I have three tables, but I was tried with only two:

```
CREATE TABLE `environment_fid` (
  `ID` mediumint(9) unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FID_environment` mediumint(9) unsigned,
  `FID_monster` mediumint(9) unsigned ,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `environment`;
CREATE TABLE `environment` (
  `ID` mediumint(9) unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

However, when I put in parts:

```
INSERT INTO environment_fid (FID_environment) VALUES (78);
```

*Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)*

and

```
 SELECT ID FROM environment WHERE name='planes';

*+----+
| ID |
+----+
| 66 |
+----+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)*
```

I have no idea about this problem, any suggestion?

Thanks,

```
INSERT INTO environment_fid (FID_environment) SELECT ID FROM environment WHERE name='planes';
```

Solve my problem, but how can I get others tables? For example:

> ```
> INSERT INTO environment_fid (FID_environment, FID_monster) 
> SELECT ID FROM environment  WHERE name='planes',
> SELECT ID FROM monster WHERE family='Blue';
> ```

Comment: Remove `VALUES` in the `INSERT INTO`

Comment: I'm noob in MySQL yet. Thank you, solved.

Comment: But, how I got the different tables?

Answer (score 2):

remove `values` and 
change your query to :

```
INSERT INTO environment_fid (FID_environment) 
SELECT ID FROM environment WHERE name='planes';
```

or

```
INSERT INTO environment_fid (FID_environment) VALUES (environment_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `VALUES` in the `INSERT INTO`. You can't mixed `VALUES` with `SELECT` in the `INSERT INTO`

So your working query will be:

```
INSERT INTO environment_fid (FID_environment) 
SELECT ID FROM environment WHERE name='planes';
```

Some sample for `INSERT INTO` statement

`INSERT INTO TableName (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (@Val1, @Val2, @Val3)`

or

```
INSERT INTO TableName (Col1, Col2, Col3) 
SELECT @Val1, @Val2, @Val3
```

Comment: If it solved your problem, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312043)

Answer (score 0):

I discover my last question:

```
INSERT INTO environment_fid (FID_environment, FID_monster) 
SELECT 
 (SELECT environment.ID FROM environment WHERE name='planes') AS FID_environment, 
 (SELECT ID FROM monster WHERE family='Blue') AS FID_monster;
```